# regex to extract "dd-mmm-yyyy" return blank array in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I try to extract `dd-mmm-yyyy` in PHP, but it's return blank array.

```
<?php

$reg = "/^[01][0-9]-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}$/";
$test = 'Composed by super, user123 to super,user123 on 31-Mar-2020 11:29 with';


preg_match( $reg, $test, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);


?>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Replace the anchors with `\b`. Also, replace `[01][0-9]` with `\d{1,2}`. See https://regex101.com/r/XB1B3x/1. Also, consider a more precise pattern, `\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(?:20|19)\d{2}\b`

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: thank you @Alex now it's works

Answer (score 0):

In your regex there are some issues:

- replace `^` and `$` with `\b`;
- you are considering only dates with days starting with `0` and `1`;
- days should be `(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`;
- years should be `(?:20|19)\d{2}`;
- remove `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` from `preg_match`.

```
<?php
$reg = "/\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-(?:20|19)\d{2}\b/";
$test = 'Composed by super, user123 to super,user123 on 31-Mar-2020 11:29 with';

preg_match($reg, $test, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: @coderInrRain It won't match `1-Jan-2021` and it will match in `1234512-Nov-0000000`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I corrected the answer to match all the possible cases of days and years